# Como puedo filtar en este JSON con typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Estoy creando una app en Ionic 5, angular 10, estoy consumiendo un api con un servicio el cual me retorno un interface tipo Menu la cual especifico asi:

```
export interface Menu {
banco: string;
itemsMenu: ItemMenu[];
```

`export interface ItemMenu { iconMenu: string; accion: string; }}`

en el componente los obtengo asi

```
this.menuService.getMenu()
            .subscribe( resp => {
              
                this.ite.push(this.a)
                const a = this.ite.find(x => x.Banco == 'Itau')
                console.log(a)
            })
```

pasa que al hacer el find me dice que es undefined y imprimo por consolo this.item.Banco tampoco por favor ayuda necesito filtrar por el key banco,
al intentar hacer el `this.ite.push(...resp.itemsMenu)` me dice que ...resp.itemsMenu es undefined

Este es el servicio que uso para obtener el json que tengo en un archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me parece raro es que al hacer `console.log(this.ite)` me arroja el Json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el Json que contiene el archivo:

[
{
"Banco": "Itau",
"ItemMenu": [
{
"IconMenu": "people-outline",
"Accion": "Cambio Gestor Comercial"
},
{
"IconMenu": "people-outline",
"Accion": "Cambio Gestor Comercial"
}
]
},
{
"Banco": "Popular",
"ItemMenu": [
{
"IconMenu": "people-outline",
"Accion": "Cambio Gestor Comercial"
}
]
}
]

Comment: de donde obtenes los datos de this.ite?, evidentemente si es undefined el error debe estar a la hora de obtener esos datos, deberías agregar mas parte del código para poder ayudarte

Comment: He agregado más código para ver si puedes por favor ayudar en algo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si el código lo escribes como texto, por qué nos lo enseñas como imagen??? Da menos trabajo copiar y pegar texto que imágenes, y a nosotros nos facilita mucho el trabajo. Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para entender cómo hacer una pregunta *correctamente*.

Comment: @DiegoBenítez falta mas código en al parte de `this.menuService.getMenu().subscribe( resp => {
            this.ite.push(this.a)
            const a = this.ite.find(x => x.Banco == 'Itau')
            console.log(a)
         })`

Comment: No sr no falta mas codigo

Answer (score 0):

Ya la he solucionado por mi cuenta a la final con dos For he solucionado mi problma

```
 CrearMenu(banco: string) {
this.items = [];
this.menuService.getMenu()
  .subscribe(resp => {
    this.menuBanco = resp
    for (let u in this.menuBanco) {
      for (let i in this.menuBanco[u].ItemMenu)

        if (this.menuBanco[u].Banco === banco) {
          this.items.push(this.menuBanco[u].ItemMenu[i])
        }
    }
  })
```